# the UnsupportedOperationException in RMI

Tags: java, rmi, remoteexception

I worked a simple program
But when you run the client at the command 
This error appears

```
 HelloClient exception:  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
```

this my coded

Interface class

```
    import java.rmi.*;

    public interface HelloInterface extends Remote { 

     public String say() throws RemoteException;


   }
```

implement class

```
           import java.rmi.RemoteException;
           import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

         /** 
           *
           * @author x
           */
   public class HelloServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements HelloInterface {

   private String message; 

   public HelloServerImpl(String msg)throws RemoteException{
   message = msg;
   }


@Override
public String say() throws RemoteException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}




 }
```

Server class

```
     import java.rmi.Naming;

       /**
        *
        * @author x
        */
       public class HelloServer {
        public static void main (String []args ){
          try {
        Naming.rebind("HELLOSERVER", new HelloServerImpl("Hello word"));
        System.out.println("Hello Server is ready.");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Hello server failed: "+ ex);
    }


    }
    }
```

Client class

```
          import java.rmi.Naming;

         /**
          *
          * @author x
          */
             public class HelloClient {
          public static void main(String[]args){

        HelloInterface hello;
        String url = "rmi://localhost/HELLOSERVER";


         try {
        hello = (HelloInterface)Naming.lookup(url);
        System.out.println(hello.say());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       System.err.println("HelloClient exception:  " + ex);
    }

    }
   }
```

I am prepared to write the steps but still the same error

why??

Comment: And the problem with executing the code you wrote is what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you wrote this yourself:

```
@Override
public String say() throws RemoteException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

Of course it throws an exception. Try to actually return a string:

```
@Override
public String say() throws RemoteException {
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: [Sorry](http://i1.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/000/015/orly.jpg), couldn't resist...